# Using law of sines to prove that larger angle is opposite to largest side in a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

As suggested by the first comment on the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776765/in-any-triangle-the-side-opposite-to-the-larger-angle-is-longer), I am trying to use law of sine to prove the result the greatest angle is opp. to greatest side. Let the triangle have angles $a,b,c$ opposite to side lengths $A,B,C$ then sine law:

$$ \frac{\sin a}{A} = \frac{\sin b}{B} = \frac{\sin c}{C} = \kappa$$

Rewriting this for side length:

$$ A = \frac{\sin a}{\kappa}$$
$$ B = \frac{\sin b}{\kappa}$$

$$ C = \frac{\sin c}{\kappa}$$

If an angle is in $\left[ 0 , \frac{\pi}{2} \right]$ then sine is strictly increasing in that domain and the greatest angle is opposite to greatest side. However, the above idea isn't applicable if the angle is in $\left[ \frac{\pi}{2} , \pi\right] $ because sine is no longer a strictly increasing function. Hence, **I want to know how to extend the proof for cases when we have an obtuse triangle.**

Comment: Use the cosine law instead. The cosine is decreasing in the range $[0,\pi]$

Comment: $a = k \sin A = k \sin(180^0 - A) = k \sin (B+C)$, $B+C \lt \pi/2$

Comment: Genius solution @MathLover Please post answer as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: @Buraian thanks for kind words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your already showed it for acute angled and right angled triangles.

For obtuse angled triangle, if $A$ is the obtuse angle,

$a = k \sin A = k \sin (180^0-A) = k \sin(B+C)$

As $B+C \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$ and sin function is increasing in $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$,

we must have $ \ \sin(B+C) \gt \sin B$ and $\sin(B+C) \gt \sin C$.

Hence $a$ is the greatest side of the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2cb.cos(\theta1)$$
$$b^2=a^2+c^2-2ac.cos(\theta2)$$
$$c^2=b^2+a^2-2ab.cos(\theta3)$$
if $\theta1 >\theta2>\theta3$ then $cos(\theta1)<cos(\theta2)<cos(\theta3)$
$$\frac{a^2-b^2-c^2}{-2cb}<\frac{b^2-a^2-c^2}{-2ca}<\frac{c^2-b^2-a^2}{-2ab}$$
sum $a^2+b^2+c^2$ and multiply to $-a.b.c$
$$a.a^2>b.b^2>c.c^2$$
as $a,b,c>0$
$$a>b>c$$

Comment: as in a triangle $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$ the inequality for $cos\theta$ holds